# How to stream binary files using MPEG-2 TS

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg2-ts

I am working on a software system to stream videos over MPEG-2 TS using FFMpeg. I have got an additional requirement of streaming pdf files. Can some one point me to the relevant link / ideas?

Simply putting pdf contents as TS payload did not work for me. I have created necessary PAT and PMT. Do I need to set PCR in adaptation field in PMT?

Comment: pdf files contains the scribe / notes for the video. I am planning to create a MPTS that contains both video and pdf as separate program.

Comment: MPEG-TS was meant for broadcasting. Wouldn't it be easier to just provide an URL to a PDF?